# Solving for unknown variables on both sides with one unknown an index.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have come across this problem while doing a question out of my textbook.
I am asking about how to solve for $x$ in this equation.

$$50x-22=1.5^{x-1}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely means $n$. A quick check on CAS seems to indicate there is no algebraic way to solve for $n$.

Comment: There is a way to solve it but the solution uses the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). That is not considered to be algebra-calculus. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+50x-22%3D%283%2F2%29%5E%28x-1%29) for the solution. Given time I could probably figure out how to get that solution but that doesn't look worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equations like this do not lend themselves to algebraic solutions.  You can use various numeric techniques to find $x$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50x-22%3D1.5%5Ex) finds two solutions, around $0.464, 16.495$  To find them yourself, start by graphing the equation, which will give you good guesses for the solutions.  You can then refine them using bisection, Newton-Raphson, or your favorite method.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to solve this algebraically. In general, mixing exponentials with polynomials leads to things we can't solve. You can solve it using something like wolfram alpha though.

Comment: Thank you! I just ended up using my CX and graphing it and finding the intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can graph both expressions that is on the left and right and check if you have any solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just use my CX and graph it.

Comment: Glad that I could help you....